# Need assistance with a tag change?

Tags: support

I edited the question "How to flatten 1/8" Baltic Birch Plywood for laser cutting?" to change the tag from plywood to wood, but afterwords realized I had misread the question.  So I attempted to change it back, but stack exchange won't revert since it doesn't detect a change from the original after I revert. It probably doesn't matter since I do not have rep yet for independent edits, but I thought I would let someone senior know in case there is any clean-up required.

Comment: Looks like the person asking the question fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!